# Need help with ODE producing error ParametricNDSolve::dsvar:

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

The function below is a function of the independent variable `a` with parameter `n0`. My goal is to get numerical value for `n0`. When I run the code, it produces the message

> ParametricNDSolve::dsvar: 23 cannot be used as a variable.

Would anyone please help me to evaluate `n0`?

```
b = 649286441/466126265;
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon;
ps = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {x''[a] + 2 x'[a] == -(357/11500) n0 Exp[x[a]], 
     x[ϵ] == x0, x'[ϵ] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[a == 1, x'[a] -> x'[a] + 714/23]}, 
    {x, x'}, {a, ϵ, b}, {n0}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30];
sol = FindRoot[Last[ps[x0]][b], {x0, -10.7, 0}, Evaluated -> False][[1, 2]]
```

Comment: the lines starting with `s =..` is missing closing `}` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks I fixed but still I can not get n0.

Comment: What problem do you solve? Your code contains a lot of errors. To fix them, one must at least know the statement of the problem.

Comment: `Exp[-x][a]` should be `Exp[-x[a]]`. And please provide the values for `\[Epsilon]`, `ri` and `x0`.

Comment: ... also, replace  of `3.14` with `Rationalize[3.14, 0]`.

Comment: See my update. Thank you!

Comment: Such an error may occure, if you have previously assigned one of the variables a value 23. Try to close Mathematica, then open it again and execute your code.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch thank you, I executed the code and got 134954.My question is this for n0 or x0?

Comment: @user60302 Who can know the answer to this question? You did not formulate the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = 649286441/466126265;
ϵ = $MachineEpsilon;
ps = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {x''[a] + 2 x'[a] == -(357/11500) n0 Exp[x[a]], 
     x[ϵ] == x0, x'[ϵ] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[a == 1, x'[a] :> (x'[a] + 714/23)]}, 
    {x, x'}, {a, ϵ, b}, {n0},
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: result]

Note change made to `WhenEvent` expression.

Comment: Great! What is the value of n0?

Comment: @user60302. The parameter `n0` has no value because you told `ParametricNDSolveValue` it was a free parameter. To get an actual solution from your oarametric family of ODEs you must assign a value to both `n0` and `x0`. You cannot solve for `n0`.

Comment: @user60302. As I see it, `ParametricNDSolveValue` returns a solver  not a solution in the normal sense. When the solver is given values for the free parameters, it then solves the ODE numerically for a specific solution and returns that solution in the form of an interpolating function. That's why you can't solve for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The author did not formulate the problem. From the discussion it became clear that we must find `n0`, under the conditions that `x0` is also unknown, but can be determined in the course of the solution. This task, apparently, does not have a single solution. I will point out one of the solutions

```
b = 649286441/466126265;
\[Epsilon] = 0`100;
xn = -10.3937674129241835084215988486799043382603309698646666546193`100.;
ps = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[a] + 
     2 x'[a] == -(357/11500) n0 Exp[x[a]], x[\[Epsilon]] == x0, 
   x'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, WhenEvent[a == 1, x'[a] -> (x'[a] + 714/23)]},
   x', {a, \[Epsilon], b}, {n0, x0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100]
FindRoot[ps[n0, xn][b], {n0, 99356}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

Even with these parameters, the solution does not converge. I will indicate only the approximate result

```
nm = 99355.5496428760234772215566854011786969761748970188973887906416640553735266314087677155869333265407520963532767501108239`100.;
```

We compute the function at these points

```
ps[nm, xn][b]

Out[]= 1.613498769806814501841157873656834618862053484217197348048863157358103610167513466653510372*10^-7
```

We display this solution

[image: fig1]

Finally, we show the function `x[a]`

```
xs = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[a] + 
     2 x'[a] == -(357/11500) n0 Exp[x[a]], x[\[Epsilon]] == x0, 
   x'[\[Epsilon]] == 0, WhenEvent[a == 1, x'[a] -> (x'[a] + 714/23)]},
   x, {a, \[Epsilon], b}, {n0, x0}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Plot[xs[nm, xn][a], {a, \[Epsilon], b}]
```

[image: fig2]